# Get current iTunesStore country

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to get currently activated iTunes store country code. I have read about getting current locale, but this is not very smart solution, since user can have one locale but totally different iTunes account. The solution does not need to be legal, apple rejection is not a problem here. Does anybody have found solution for this scenario using private frameworks?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this after you've requested the store's products by checking the NSLocale on one of the product's priceLocale. Try this code:

```
- (NSString*) storeCountryCode:(NSArray*) products
{
    NSString* countryCode = nil;
    SKProduct* product = [products objectAtIndex:0];
    if(product != nil)
    {
        NSLocale* storeLocale = product.priceLocale;
        countryCode = (__bridge NSString*)CFLocaleGetValue((__bridge CFLocaleRef)storeLocale, kCFLocaleCountryCode);
    }
    return countryCode;
}
```

You could call this from your SKProductsRequestDelegate method:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSString* storeCountryCode = [self storeCountryCode:response.products]; 
    //other product handling
}
```

Comment: Yes this is solution, but the app will be produced with enterprise licence, and there inAppPurchase is not allowed, right?

Comment: An enterprise application doesn't exist in the App Store, so no, it cannot use in app purchases

Answer (score 0):

you can "CFLocaleGetValue" call this use
 `NSString *aCountry=[getCurrentItunesStoreCountryFromProudct:myProudct];`

```
-(NSString *)getCurrentItunesStoreCountryFromProudct:(SKProduct *)aProudct
{
 NSLocale* storeLocale = aProudct.priceLocale;
 NSString *storeCountry = (NSString*)CFLocaleGetValue((CFLocaleRef)storeLocale,   kCFLocaleCountryCode);
return storeCountry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the [Storefront ID](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store.html#appendix) with this code. As it relies on private APIs, do not use in production code.

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL loaded = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework"] loadAndReturnError:&error];
if (loaded) {
    NSString *localStoreFrontID = nil;
    @try {
        localStoreFrontID = [NSClassFromString(@"ISClient") valueForKeyPath:@"currentClient.localStoreFrontID"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", exception);
    }

    NSLog(@"localStoreFrontID: %@", localStoreFrontID);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

On iOS 5.1.1, this printed `localStoreFrontID: 143459-2,2` for me, i.e. the Swiss store. I’m not sure what the `-2,2` suffix mean, maybe it is about the language. I have not tested this on iOS 6.

Note that it even works after you sign out of your account in Settings → Store.

Comment: I tested on a device running 6.1. localStoreFrontID returns null.